# javascript: create an array of JSON objects from linking two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, javascript-objects

let's say I have two arrays:

```
  var  meals: ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"];
  var ingredients: [["eggs", "yogurt", "toast"],["falafel", "mushrooms", "fries"], ["pasta", "cheese"];
```

Is there an elegant solution to create an array of JavaScript objects which features:

```
var dailySchedule = {"breakfast" : ["eggs", "yogurt", "toast"],
                      "lunch": ["falafel", "mushrooms", "fries"],
                      "dinner": ["pasta", "cheese"]
}
```

I know it should be something with .reduce but I keep scratching my head how to do it...

Comment: use a `for(...)` loop :)

Comment: JSON is text data, what you are after is plain JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could reduce it

```js
var meals = ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"];
var ingredients = [
  ["eggs", "yogurt", "toast"],
  ["falafel", "mushrooms", "fries"],
  ["pasta", "cheese"]
];

var dailySchedule = meals.reduce( (a,b, i) => {
 return a[b] = ingredients[i], a;
},{});

console.log(dailySchedule)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top : 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

> The **`forEach()`** method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var meals = ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"],
    ingredients = [["eggs", "yogurt", "toast"], ["falafel", "mushrooms", "fries"], ["pasta", "cheese"]],
    dailySchedule = {};

meals.forEach(function (k, i) {
    this[k] = ingredients[i];
}, dailySchedule);        

console.log(dailySchedule);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant way that i can think of is this;

```js
var   meals = ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"],
ingredients = [["eggs", "yogurt", "toast"],["falafel", "mushrooms", "fries"], ["pasta", "cheese"]],
     result = Object.assign(...meals.map((m,i) => ({[m]:ingredients[i]})));
console.log(result);
```